# xVal client-side validation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xval

I downloaded the xVal sample project  from [Steve Sanderson’s blog](http://blog.codeville.net/2009/01/10/xval-a-validation-framework-for-aspnet-mvc/), run it, and the sever side validation it's working (after i click submit), but the client side doesn't;
although i looked at the source and saw the generated javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">xVal.AttachValidator("booking", {"Fields":[{"FieldName":"ClientName","FieldRules":[{"RuleName":"Required","RuleParameters":{}},{"RuleName":"StringLength","RuleParameters":{"MaxLength":"3"}}]},{"FieldName":"NumberOfGuests","FieldRules":[{"RuleName":"Range","RuleParameters":{"Min":"1","Max":"20","Type":"decimal"}},{"RuleName":"DataType","RuleParameters":{"Type":"Integer"}}]},{"FieldName":"ArrivalDate","FieldRules":[{"RuleName":"DataType","RuleParameters":{"Type":"Date"}},{"RuleName":"Required","RuleParameters":{}}]}]})</script>
```

my view code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CreateBooking.aspx.cs" Inherits="BookingsDemo.Views.Home.CreateBooking" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="DomainModel"%>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h1>Place a booking</h1>

    <% using(Html.BeginForm()) { %>
        <div>
            Your name: <%= Html.TextBox("booking.ClientName") %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("booking.ClientName") %>
        </div>
        <div>
            Number of guests: <%= Html.TextBox("booking.NumberOfGuests")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("booking.NumberOfGuests")%>
        </div>
        <div>
            Expected arrival date: <%= Html.TextBox("booking.ArrivalDate")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("booking.ArrivalDate")%>
        </div>                
        <input type="submit" />       
    <% } %>
    <%= Html.ClientSideValidation<Booking>("booking") %>    
</asp:Content>
```

here is the generated html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /><title>

</title><link href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.2.6.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/xVal.jquery.validate.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
            </div>

            <div id="menucontainer">


            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">

    <h1>Place a booking</h1>
    <form action="/Home/CreateBooking" method="post">
        <div>
            Your name: <input id="booking_ClientName" name="booking.ClientName" type="text" value="" />

        </div>
        <div>
            Number of guests: <input id="booking_NumberOfGuests" name="booking.NumberOfGuests" type="text" value="" />


        </div>
        <div>
            Expected arrival date: <input id="booking_ArrivalDate" name="booking.ArrivalDate" type="text" value="" />

        </div>                

        <input type="submit" />       
    </form><script type="text/javascript">xVal.AttachValidator("booking", {"Fields":[{"FieldName":"ClientName","FieldRules":[{"RuleName":"Required","RuleParameters":{}},{"RuleName":"StringLength","RuleParameters":{"MaxLength":"15"}}]},{"FieldName":"NumberOfGuests","FieldRules":[{"RuleName":"Range","RuleParameters":{"Min":"1","Max":"20","Type":"decimal"}},{"RuleName":"DataType","RuleParameters":{"Type":"Integer"}}]},{"FieldName":"ArrivalDate","FieldRules":[{"RuleName":"DataType","RuleParameters":{"Type":"Date"}},{"RuleName":"Required","RuleParameters":{}}]}]})</script>


            <div id="footer">
                My Sample MVC Application &copy; Copyright 2008
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: everything seems ok. Have you referenced the javascript?

Comment: yes, i added the generated html

Comment: If you update your jquery to jquery-1.3.2 does it works?

Comment: i tried 1.3.2.min, and it doesn't work

Comment: tried without min (jquery-1.3.2.js) also doesn't work

Comment: and if you use a validation summary?

Comment: no, it doesn't help, only for the server, if i click submit everything goes red

Comment: Are you sure a request is sent to the server? Because it is normal thaat client side valdiation is triggered if you click on submit button

Comment: I think you downloaded a demo for xVal 0.8 BETA. There is demo for v1.0 here: http://blog.codeville.net/2009/09/17/xval-v10-now-available/

Comment: yes, i put some breakpoins, and they hit, so it is a request to the server

Comment: i created a new project, used the newest version of jquery and xval, and it still doesn't work

Comment: you say that you created new project. Did you tried just to run the Booking demo v1.0 you downloaded? It works fine for me. Also demo for version v0.8 beta does not work for me either.

Comment: everything is working in my new project, i just needed to add all the jquery references. i would like to see the Booking demo you are talking about, could you please provide me with a link ?

Comment: of course: http://blog.codeville.net/blogfiles/2009/September/BookingsDemo-1.0.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the client side validation doesn't work in the demo downloaded from that  blog,
but with the new versions of jquery and xVal everything works fine :)